# save the socket of a user to be used on different pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

**Description :**

I have the following code snippet that seems to work great

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>

 var socket = io();

</script>
```

Now with socket created I am using it to do different tasks that user wants e.g user is chatting with other online people ... Now what if user navigates to some other page and performs something else ... for that I am going to need the same socket that was assigned to that user ... I have an array on the server side that holds all the sockets of connected user along with their id ...

How can I keep the socket with me all the times while visiting different pages of the website..

e.g I  click on a link and that takes me to a page ... Now I post something on that page for that I want the socket that was given to me .

Comment: Use a router library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot preserve a socket from one page to the next.

If the user is going to navigate among pages, then you will need to do two things:

1. As each page is loaded reconnect your socket to the server for that newly loaded page.
2. On the server, process the disconnect events so you can remove sockets from users that navigated away and then your normal code for processing the connect event will see them reconnect on the new page.

---

Your other choice is to change your application so that it changes content of the page, but never actually navigates to a new URL, thus preserving the Javascript state (and any connected sockets) as the user changes content.  This is sometimes known as a single page design.  You would typically use Ajax calls to fetch new content and then DOM manipulation calls to change what the user sees in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a single page application (website), that loads all contents by using Ajax and not navigating away from base page.

Other old dirty solution (than can be even more complex) is to use page with `iframe` and load all contents there, but keep your SocketIO instances in parent page. have in mind, that in this case the url of page won't change, so users won't be able to bookmark it properly.